# Who pays for Air Traffic Control services?

Tags: faa-regulations, passenger

I imagine certain fees from flight boarding sales are paid to the FAA, but who is responsible for paying fees for passenger flights?

Comment: What do you mean "fees for passenger flights"?

Comment: Typically there are landing fees for large aircraft at airports. There is no standard amount or standard way of calculating them (or at least there wasn't back in the 1990s). Airports had widely varying fee schedules. Whether there was (or is) a differentiation in fees for pax or cargo I do not know. As I remember the landing fee for a 747 at KJFK back in 1999 when I retired was over $12,000. The fees went to the airport, not to the FAA. It might be interesting to post a question to see what the landing fees are at major airports these days.

Comment: @Terry Thank you for a great explanation. I was wondering what that has to do with ATC though, as per question title.

Comment: @digitgopher I was attempting, perhaps poorly, to respond to the question in your comment as well as to add a little more info as to where money goes. You are right that it has nothing to do with ATC, but as often happens with questions, the question text is more expansive than the title. My comment indeed did not address the title at all, which is why I put it in as a comment rather than an answer. However, it did address, however poorly, what I felt the questioner might have meant to include in "fees for passenger flights."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FAA Funding is currently a mix of General Fund(taxes everyone pays) and Airway Trust Fund(ticket taxes and fuel taxes) money. The breakdowns are shown in: https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/aatf/media/AATF_Fact_Sheet.pdf